# Insert char array to char array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to insert a char array in  another char array

```
char TEST[100]="www.bing.com ";

char headers[256] = "GET /index HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.bing.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)\r\nReferer: \r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
```

As you can see, I would like to insert the www.bing.com in the 2nd array

```
  char headers[256] = "GET /index HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+TEST[100]+"\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)\r\nReferer: \r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You just did, didn't you?

Comment: @ScottHunter error -> invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’

Answer (score 4):

```
char buffer[512];
sprintf(buffer, "GET /index HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)\r\nReferer: \r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n", TEST);
```

`buffer` now contains the result you want (note how I used `%s` in the format string to embed `TEST` inside the HTTP Request string)